# Sum of two list numbers in a table

Tags: python, python-3.5

I have, for example, two lists of numbers:

```
List_numbers_1 = [3, 54, -30]
List_numbers_2 = [65, 8, 800]
```

I want to create a function that runs the following table of sums:

```
  3 +  65 =  68
 54 +   8 =  62
-30 + 800 = 770
```

The table is lined up, and that is my goal. In order to creat that function I have create other 3 functions that maybe will help me:

```
'''it returns the width of a number '''
def max_width(List_numbers_1):
    string_List_numbers_1 = map(str, List_numbers_1)
    width_List_numbers_1 = map(len, string_List_numbers_1)
    return max(width_List_numbers_1)

Output: 3
'''it returns the padd for a number'''

def left_padded(number, width):
    return str(number).rjust(width)

left_padded(54, 5)
'   54'
left_padded(-56, 5)
'  -56'
'''It returns a padd for all the numbers of the list'''
def all_left_padded(List_numbers_1, width):
    return list(map(lambda number: left_padded(number, width), List_numbers_1))

all_left_padded(List_numbers_1, 5)
['    3', '   54', '  -30']
```

I think the above functions can be useful for my last function. Nevertheless, I will really appreciate any other idea. If it is possible I would prefer a function that use the return statement but with `print()` will be ok.

I fact I think this function has to contain return and print as well.

THANK YOU

Comment: Why don't you just use numpy?

Comment: I dont know numpy. I will check out. It can create the structure of numbers right?

Comment: Nevertheless I only hope that my functions can be useful in numpy

Comment: this is one of the weird times that the code is easier in Haskell than in Python. `zipWith (+) lst1 lst2`

Answer (score 1):

Without numpy, you can zip the lists together and add them up:

```
[sum(i) for i in zip(lst1,lst2)]
```

It is easier to use a list comprehension rather than `map`

For formatting the numbers it is natural to use `str.format()`.

As you don't know the widths of the numbers in advance, you first create
a format string, and the easiest way to do that is to use `format`

```
# maxlen returns the length of the longest element
def maxlen(l):
  return max([len(str(i)) for i in l])

# sumtable returns a formatted multiline string containing the sums
# written in a human readable form.
def sumtable(l1,l2):
  #sums contains the answers, and table is the full table numbers in
  #the calculations as a list of tuples
  sums = [sum(i) for i in zip(l1,l2)]
  table = list(zip(l1,l2,sums))

  width1 = maxlen(l1)
  width2 = maxlen(l2)
  widthsum = maxlen(sums)

  # formatstring has a form like "{:3d} + {:5d} = {:5d}\n" 
  formatstring = "{{:{}d}} + {{:{}d}} = {{:{}d}}\n".format(width1,width2,widthsum)

  # unpack the values from the table into the format string and return.
  return (formatstring.format(*table[0])
         + formatstring.format(*table[1])
         + formatstring.format(*table[2]))

print(sumtable([3,54,-30],[65,8,800]))

#   3 +  65 =  68
#  54 +   8 =  62
# -30 + 800 = 770
```

Comment: Waoooo thank you very much. Soon I will add my result

Comment: Excelent your function

Comment: What I dont understand is de structure of that formatstring because is still for me too complex

Comment: insert a debugging `print (formatstring)` and try with a few test values.

Comment: James when. I am trying your function the output is "name maxlen is not defined". Why?

Comment: hi james I am sorry because I dont know how to post my function here. But the above function has the same structure than yours. Just I dont see the way to displays that table USING 'first column' 'second_column' and the third one. I am sure it has to be a way to do it. but I dont find it. Could you do it. I would appreciate it

Comment: >def table(L1, L2):
  ....Sum = list(map(lambda x, y: x + y, L1, L2))
 .... widthL1 = max_width(L1)
 .... widthL2 = max_width(L2)
 .... widthSum = max_width(Sum)
 ....first_column = all_left_padded(L1, widthL1)
 ....second column = all_left_padded(L2, widthL2)
 ....third_column = all_left_padded(Sum, widthsum)
 ....return '{} + {} = {}'.format(*first_column, *second_column, *Third_column)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a 3rd party library, this is trivial with `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

lst1 = [3, 54, -30]
lst2 = [65, 8, 800]

res = np.sum([lst1, lst2], axis=0)

# array([ 68,  62, 770])
```

Comment: Thanks but what I want is display the table of sums, not only de sums, I mean: a + b = c, not only c, and for all the different rows and using specifically my columns. Nevertheless thanks for your idea

Answer (score 0):

```
`in order to display the table of sums''' 
>def table(L1, L2):
    Sum = list(map(lambda x, y: x + y, L1, L2))
    widthL1 = max_width(L1)
    widthL2 = max_width(L2)
    widthSum = max_width(Sum)
    first_column = all_left_padded(L1, widthL1)
    second_column = all_left_padded(L2, widthL2)
    third_column = all_left_padded(Sum, widthsum)
    triplets = zip(first_column, second_column, third_column)
    return list(map(lambda triplet: str_sum(triplet), triplets))

  # for displaying the table
  >def printable(L1, L2):
           t = table(L1, L2)
           for row in t:
                 print(row)
```

# the str_sum function was:

> def str_sum(Tuple):
>                  return '{ } + { } = { }'.format(Tuple)

```
  > str_sum((2,3,5))
      '2 + 3 = 5'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  # I was thinking: why instead summing two Lists, I will sum n lists?
  # I would create two functions
   >L1 = [1, 2]
   >L2 = [2, 3]
   > L3 = [4, 5]
   > Group = (L1, L2, L3)
   > Sum = [sum(l) for l in zip(*Group)]
   >Sum
    [7, 10]

  # and for creating a Tuple with n elements because if the table has n Lists the Tuple must have n elements
   > def str_sum(Tuple):
             n = len (Tuple)
             f = ((n -2)*'{ } + ' + '{ } = { }')
             return f.format(*Tuple)

      >str_sum((1, 2, 3, 8, 7, 21))
      ('1 + 2 + 3 + 8 + 7 = 21')
```